# Why do we need service layer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I'm currently learning Spring Boot and I've seen how people create a controller, inject the service class and in the service class inject the repository.

Why do we need the service class as a middleman and why can't we just inject the repository into controller?

Here's the tutorial that confused me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpcOSXWPXTk&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x

Comment: This question will likely attract opinionated answers (you can see that already happening with the current answers), so I'm voting to close this question as **primarily opinion-based**. Related: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @g00glen00b I reply now despite your comment is pre-covid (that means old already) But I really have to say this. "will likely attract opinionated answers": All answer are opinioned as longs are they are coming from a Human being. Now I get why you wrote that., which is for the whole 'stack overflow opinion-based questions" but I think for this one, you exaggerate quite a bit. The question is valid and is asking for a pattern used in a Framework (but actually used in Java in general) so. Guess what, frameworks are opinioned. But it doesn't mean that someone can't ask what X is done using Y...

Answer (score 29):

You don't always need a service layer. Especially if your APIs are just simple CRUD operations, for example, with no real logic required or calculations.

However, if you have an API which performs some logic before querying your repository then this should be in a separate service class. This is good practice arising from what is known as the single responsibility principle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

- Your Controller's single responsibility should be to handle the
  incoming request.
- The Service layer's single responsibility is to do any logic required with the data received by the Controller.
- The repository's single responsibility is to query the data base.

Answer (score 13):

Layered architectures are generally suypported by this contention:

> We use layers to allow us to abstract away the underlying implementation so we that we can easily change it.

A happy side effect of layering is that - if followed faithfully - it can make the system more testable by (a) using interfaces to define each layer and (b) encouraging separation of concerns.

So, that's the principle (briefly, at least) but like any principle it can be misunderstood and misapplied.

While the benefits of layering to hide data access from the view layer (and vice versa) are solid in *most* cases, the benefits of including a service layer between the view layer  and the data layer are not always so compelling. A system which has  ...

- A small number of controllers
- A small number of repositories
- A 1:1 mapping between controller and repository
- No need for complex transformations between domain representations (for repositories) and view representations (for controllers)

... probably doesn't need a service layer.

Whereas, a system which has  ...

- Large numbers of controller and repositories
- Complex relationshiops betwen controllers and repositores e.g. maybe a controller uses multiple repositories and combines their results or invokes these repositories in a chain
- Complex transformations between domain representations (for repositories) and view representations (for controllers)

... probably does need a service layer.

Answer (score -1):

Thats a way to separate service functionality from transport, your service defines a functionality that cover a single responsability (SOLID), and that can be exposed using different ports (Hexagonal Architecture), for example HTTP/REST or AMQP.

Adding a service layer give you the flexibility to change your port in the future, or use more than one.

Answer (score -1):

It is like this so you don't have to put a lot of code inside the RestController layer, which should be clean and only with code related to communications.

So all the logic and the IFs etc. should stay in the Controller layer.

The Repository layer should stick to the *interfacing* way, which should not have any code inside the methods, but only the layout of how the data is obtained, but not its logic.

Answer (score -2):

The Spring boot controller is an interface to the outside world, not much different than a UI for example.
Just like you want to be able to have more than one UI flavour, you might more than one interface to your business logic. Especially if you want it to be long lived and adaptable to future API frameworks. 
If your logic was embedded in the controller, you have to do quite some refactoring when you arrive at that point.

So the need of a separate controller depends on the complexity of your logic.