# What is the use of service layer in Spring Boot applications?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am new to Spring Boot and I am creating a RESTful API with no UI.

I am thinking if I should use business service and call repository from there or just call the repository directly from my REST controller?

Comment: Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442790/why-do-we-need-service-layer You can get your answer from here

Comment: thanks @PratikSherke that link is useful. I tried looking for it before posting my own quesiton but couldnt find it. Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Service layer is not a concept exclusive from Spring Boot. It's a software architectural term and frequently referred as a pattern. Simple applications *may skip* the service layer. In practical terms, nothing stops you from invoking a repository method from the controller layer.

But, I *strongly* advise the usage of a service layer, as it is primarily meant to define the application boundaries. The service layer responsibilities include (but are not limited to):

- Encapsulating the business logic implementation;
- Centralizing data access;
- Defining where the transactions begin/end.

Quoting the [Service Layer pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) from Martin Fowler's [Catalog of Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/):

> A Service Layer defines an application's boundary and its set of available operations from the perspective of interfacing client layers. It encapsulates the application's business logic, controlling transactions and coor-dinating responses in the implementation of its operations.

Answer (score 29):

Separation of concerns is the key:

- **The controller (presentation layer, or port)** is a protocol interface which exposes application functionality as RESTful web services. It should do that and nothing more.
- **The repository (persistence layer, or adapter)** abstracts persistence operations: find (by id or other criteria), save (create, update) and delete records. It should do that and nothing more.
- **The service layer** (domain) contains your business logic. It defines which functionalities you provide, how they are accessed, and what to pass and get in return - **independent on any port (of which there may be multiple: web services, message queues, scheduled events) and independent on its internal workings** (it's nobody's business that the service uses the repository, or even how data is represented in a repository). The service layer may translate 1:1 from the repositiory data, or may apply filtering, transformation or aggregation of additional data.

The business logic may start simple at the beginning, and offer no more than  simple CRUD operations, but that doesn't mean it will forever stay this way. As soon as you need to deal with access rights, it's no longer a matter of routing requests from the controller directly to the repository, but checking access and filtering data as well. Requests may need validation and consistency checks before hitting the database, rules and additional operations may be applied, so your **services get more value over time**.

Even for simple CRUD cases, I'd introduce a service layer, which at least translates from DTOs to Entities and vice versa.

**Keep your controllers/repositories (or ports and adapters) stupid, and your services smart, and you get a maintainable and well-testable solution.**